# Why won't SQLite let me query a specific ATTACHED database?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

```
SQLite version 3.7.3
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'test.db' AS 12;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM ids;
1|hi
2|hilo
3|hiloa
4|hiloas
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main
2    12               C:\test.db
sqlite> SELECT * FROM 12.ids;
Error: unrecognized token: "12.ids"
```

Why is it erroring? The data is clearly there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `12`.ids;
```

If you're going to use odd names (such as all-numeric ones), you'd better escape them properly.